# Quero salvar 3 números e depois imprimir na tela

Tags: java, array

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] vet = new int[2];
        int i;

        for (i=0; i<2; i++); {
            System.out.println("Digite um numero");
            vet[i] = sc.nextInt();

        }   
         for (i=0; i<2; i++);{
             System.out.println(vet[i]);
         }

            sc.close();

    }     
}
```

Dá um erro na linha `vet[i] = sc.nextInt();`

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
>   at Main.main(Main.java:12)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há um `;` onde não deveria aí, você está encerrando o `for`sem fazer nada (ele encerra no `;` sem ter um bloco a executar), aí abre um bloco único isolado, sem pertencer ao `for` onde obviamente pega o valor `i` já incrementado pela última vez no `for` e ele vale 2, o valor que indica que deve encerrar o laço, daí vai acessar o índice usando essa variável e cai fora da faixa. Assim funciona:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] vet = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite um numero");
            vet[i] = sc.nextInt();

        }   
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) System.out.println(vet[i]);
    }     
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xZTYAz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ForBlock). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/ForBLock.java).

Note o detalhe que eu declarei a variável dentro do laço. Algumas pessoas acham bobagem fazer isso, outros fazem a declaração fora porque aprenderam errado que é melhor fazer antes (o melhor é fazer o mais perto do seu uso, com o menor escopo possível), e se tivesse feito a declaração no `for` daria erro mais óbvio nessa situação e já aconteceria na compilação que é muito melhor. Tem recomendações que parecem frescura, mas elas existem porque são úteis.

Comment: vlw, muito obrigado, entendi onde estava o erro